# Kubernetes unusable when disconnected from internet (Windows)

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, local

I'm using Docker for Windows with Kubernetes. If I'm disconnected from the internet and restart my computer or restart Kubernetes, then it gets stuck in a perpetual `kubernetes is starting...` mode. I can run `kubectl proxy` but anything else fails.

eg `kubectl get pod` gives me `Unable to connect to the server: EOF`

**Edit: Solution**

- Uncheck the `Automatically check for updates` box in the Kubernetes General Settings fixed it for me.
- (optional) Change your deployments to use `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`. I did this for my `kubernetes-dashboard` deployment.

[image]

Oddly, the kubernetes status would still get stuck in `Kubernetes is starting...` even though I was able to interact with it via `kubectl`

Following @aurleius's answer, I tried patching my `compose` and `compose-api` deployments but those settings were lost whenever I reset via the docker right click menu. I wrote a powershell script to patch the deployment so I'm putting it here just in case.

```
# Patch compose
kubectl patch deployment compose -n docker -p "{ \`"spec\`": { \`"template\`": { \`"spec\`": { \`"containers\`": [{ \`"name\`": \`"compose\`", \`"imagePullPolicy\`": \`"IfNotPresent\`" }] } } } }"

# Patch compose-api
kubectl patch deployment compose-api -n docker -p "{ \`"spec\`": { \`"template\`": { \`"spec\`": { \`"containers\`": [{ \`"name\`": \`"compose\`", \`"imagePullPolicy\`": \`"IfNotPresent\`" }] } } } }"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested  your scenario on Mac and Windows and a short answer to this is that by default you require Internet connection to run Kubernetes cluster correctly.

The reason for that is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#network):

> An Internet connection is required. Images required to run the
>   Kubernetes server are downloaded and instantiated as containers, and
>   the Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\kubectl.exe` command is installed.

What the documentation is not specifying is that the images which are used to run Kubernetes on Docker are possibly instantly checking for updates and new images for docker pods.

On Windows you can see that when you turn off the internet, close Docker and then run it again you can see that:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
docker        compose-7447646cf5-hzdbl                     0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   0          21m
docker        compose-api-6fbc44c575-b5b47                 0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          21m
kube-system   etcd-docker-for-desktop                      1/1     Running            1          20m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-docker-for-desktop            1/1     Running            1          20m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-docker-for-desktop   1/1     Running            1          20m
kube-system   kube-dns-86f4d74b45-chzdc                    3/3     Running            3          21m
kube-system   kube-proxy-xsksv                             1/1     Running            1          21m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-docker-for-desktop            1/1     Running            1          20m


> PS C:\Users\Administrator> kubectl get pods -n kube-system Unable to
> connect to the server: EOF
```

Machines go to `CrashLoopBackOff` or `ImagePullBackOff` so Kubernetes Cluster is not running because it can't download new images according to it's policies. 
I have found how to prevent this error:

`PS C:\Users\Administrator> kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces                                                                                                                                                                          NAMESPACE     NAME          DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE                                                                                                                                                                 docker        compose       1         1         1            1           33m                                                                                                                                                                 docker        compose-api   1         1         1            1           33m                                                                                                                                                                 kube-system   kube-dns      1         1         1            1           33m`

You can see the deployments and now we can change the [Image Pull Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/) to IfNotPresent. Note that we have to do it with both deployments in docker namespace. 
 Edit it:
`PS C:\Users\Administrator> kubectl edit deployment compose -n docker`

```
spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --kubeconfig
        - ""
        - --reconciliation-interval
        - 30s
        image: docker/kube-compose-controller:v0.3.9
        imagePullPolicy: Alwaysspec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --kubeconfig
        - ""
        - --reconciliation-interval
        - 30s
        image: docker/kube-compose-controller:v0.3.9
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

The difference between Mac and Windows is that Mac shows the error after some time while Windows ends in a loop. Hope this helps.

**Update:**
From what I've seen there are several scenarios. Interestingly the update checkbox had no impact on these events:
1) editing deployments and offline restart (laptop restart) does not overwrite the imagePullPolicy
2) editing deployments and online laptop restart does not overwrite the imagePullPolicy
3) if by restart you understood the Cluster restart option in the Docker menu, then yes it overwrites all the deployment files. 
I looked for those yaml files but they are nowhere to be found in Windows file system, also I am not sure if that would work since it would change the checksum of those files and Docker could not take it. Other option is that it might be just impossible since the docker on Windows:

> Images required to run the Kubernetes server are downloaded and
>   instantiated as containers

Comment: Good answer although editing the policy didn't fix it for me and it reset every time I reset. I acutally fixed it by unchecking `Automatically check for updates` in the General Settings

Comment: Also, I don't always have the `compose` deployment but I do have the `compose-api` deployment.

Comment: Is there any way to install the required kubernetes containers or images manually. I don't not have any direct internet access from my work machine. I can copy the required image to some folder and trigger the installing from there...