# Kubernetes fails to start on Docker Desktop without direct internet access

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I'm running Docker Desktop 3.6.0 on Windows 10 with WSL2.
When I try to enable Kubernetes I only see "Failed to start" within the Docker Desktop UI.
Docker itself works fine. Not sure how I can get any further logs.

Here the output from kubectl version:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3", GitCommit:"ca643a4d1f7bfe34773c74f79527be4afd95bf39", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-15T21:04:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Error from server (InternalError): an error on the server ("") has prevented the request from succeeding
```

From other posts it seems that and internet connections is required for initial setup:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765732/1100559
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318739/1100559

Direct internet connection is not possible on my work environment, I can only manually copy required images on my pc.
I also do not have admin access.

Is there a way to manually setup Kubernetes on Docker Desktop or somehow indicate where the required images can be found?

I have a nexus Docker repository where I can push required images to.
I have changed the `~\.docker\daemon.json` and added my docker repository in insecure-registries. After first login docker is able to pull images from there and run them.

Already tried to reset or enable and disable Kubernetes. Also deleting ~/.kube/config did not work.

Comment: One possible way is to setup a localhost docker registry on the air gapped machine and then push the Kubernetes specific images to this server. Of course you would first need to download/pull the k8s images on your local workstation.
https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-an-externally-accessible-registry

Comment: Okay I thought about something like that but I don't know exactly which images I need to pull. Do you know which ones I need? I have a nexus docker repository where I can push images.

Comment: Are you really stuck with using Docker Desktop? You can use `k3s` which does what you need:
https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/airgap/

Comment: I have no admin right, it will be complicated to get other software approved. But I can run any docker containers. Can I install k3s on running docker?

Comment: Yes, you can use `k3d` https://k3d.io/v5.1.0/

Answer (score 1):

High level answer...

1. Get a docker registry

   1. If you work for an old skool cool enterprise; use [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory)
   2. If you just want to get it to work; use [Harbor](https://goharbor.io/)
   3. GitHub and GitLab (depending on license) have registries available too...
2. Edit the docker daemon on the kubernetes nodes (your workstation) to only pull from these registries.

   1. if redhat; `/etc/containers/registries.conf`
   2. if debain; `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
   3. you might be able to hack a `/etc/hosts` entry too...
3. Populate the new registry
4. Run kubernetes and yoiu should be good to go.  Depending on the configuration you choose you may need to add a [registry credential secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think it does not really answer my question:
As mentioned I'm running on Windows 10 with Docker Desktop and I have a Nexus Docker registry. 
I have already added my docker registry in insecure-registries within the daemon.json but that did not help.

Comment: Did you try the hacky `/etc/hosts` entry? (Or I guess in your case `C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` or something like that -- it has been a while)

Comment: Also doing dev without admin access... https://memes.yarn.co/yarn-clip/45c2e073-8f2b-436b-ab7c-25591fa3f906

Maybe an excuse to play with https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/